# Firestore how to putExtra object using Geopoint

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Objects that implements serializable are very useful because can be pass in the extras of an intent:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, SomeActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("key", someObject);
startActivity(intent);
```

And then get it in the other Activity:

```
MyObjectUsinGeoPoint Object = (MyObjectUsinGeoPoint) getIntent().getSerializableExtra("key");
```

The problem is, I'm getting this error:

```
Caused by: java.io.NotSerializableException: com.google.firebase.firestore.GeoPoint
```

I try to make `GeoPoint` implements `Serializable` by creating an inner class inside my model:

```
private class GeoBetter extends GeoPoint implements Serializable {

    public GeoBetter(double v, double v1) {
        super(v, v1);
    }
}
```

and then initialize it in the constructor:

```
public MyObjectUsinGeoPoint(double latitude, double longitude) {
    geoPoint = new GeoBetter(latitude, longitude);
}
```

But I got this other error:

```
Caused by: java.io.InvalidClassException: com.domain.tupas.models.MyObjectUsinGeoPoint$GeoBetter; no valid constructor
```

How can I put in an extra for an Intent that contains an Object that is not serializable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try bellow approach :

```
private GeoPoint location;

@Override
public void writeToParcel(Parcel parcel, int i)
{
    parcel.writeDouble(location.getLatitude());
    parcel.writeDouble(location.getLongitude());
}

public UserModel(Parcel in)
{
    Double lat = in.readDouble();
    Double lng = in.readDouble();
    location = new GeoPoint(lat, lng);
}
```

It works if the class is not too complex (like GeoPoint), otherwise you need to find different approach.

Comment: Seems like it could work, can you share the complete class and a couple of examples?

Comment: Here you go : https://gist.github.com/adityahas/7729153e522e2c6d184aa641d070aef1

What example do you need in particular?

Comment: Well that model seem self explanatory, I'm gonna try it and let you know, please be patient, I'm currently on other project

Comment: I made few tries but can't make it out work straightforward. Once the other Activity get it getParcelableExtra, I got 0,0 in the GeoPoint coordinates... however, parcelable seems to be the way to do it. Can you think in something else? Maybe I'm doing something wrong

Comment: Can I see the code? It's working as intended on my side.

Comment: Dear friend, sorry for taking this long, a good old night of insomnia was all I need to find some spare time. You are right, adding my own gist to this comment section, you deserve your points
https://gist.github.com/cutiko/f26c4e9db6c27f55696dab9849a84545

Comment: Works like a charm, especially useful for lists of objects that have geopoint fields.

Comment: what if I need GeoPoint list as parcellable?

Answer (score 0):

you can achieve same goal by sending `android.location.Location` object as `Parcelable` extra since location object already implement `Parcelable` interface

then in another activity you can get location object from intent and constract a new `com.google.firebase.firestore.GeoPoint` object and set it to your own model
like this simple example :-

1- first get the location object and pass it as Parcelable  extra to intent

```
@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

    Intent intent = new Intent(context,AnotherActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra("extraLocation",location);
    context.startActivity(intent);
}
```

or you can create location object and give it latitude and longitude manually

```
Location location = new Location(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER); // any provider 
location.reset();
location.setLatitude(latitude);
location.setLongitude(longitude);
```

2- in another activity get the location object from Intent extra

```
Location location = getIntent().getParcelableExtra("extraLocation");
GeoPoint geoPoint = geoPointFromLocation(location);
```

3- this is a simple method to convert the location object to GeoPoint

```
 private GeoPoint geoPointFromLocation(Location location) {

        GeoPoint geoPoint = new GeoPoint(location.getLatitude(),location.getLongitude());
        return geoPoint ;
    }
```

and finally you can set the GeoPoint object inside your model.

Comment: Why would this work, like in my case there would be Geopoint field inside the Object being passed in the Intent, did you test it?

Comment: If you make GeoPoint field as transient you can avoid the exception but then the field be null after you got it from intent , a workaround is passing the location to intent , since both hold same data ,  I hope firebase team make GeoPoint implement parcelable interface so then we can pass it easily with intent

Comment: Dude! I'm literally anxious about getting a release with geo queries